# Dynamic menu - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So far I have -

```
@model IEnumerable<Hub.Models.MenuModel>
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.MenuModel) {
       <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.View, item.Controller, item.MenuName)</li>

    }
</ul>
```

where ViewBag.MenuModel contains View, Controller and MenuName string properties.

How do I get those out within this View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your controller it is hard to determine why this would not be working, it could be that ViewBag.MenuModel is not set, or it's not of the correct type.

In your current code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Hub.Models.MenuModel>  @*THIS LINE CREATES A STRONGLY-TYPED VIEW*@
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.MenuModel) {
       <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.View, item.Controller, item.MenuName)</li>

    }
</ul>
```

That first line strongly-types the view for the MenuModel.

Yet you are passing the model to the View using the ViewBag.

You can send the Model to the view by using:

```
return View(model)
```

in your controller, where model is the instance of the MenuModel you are passing to the view.

In the view you can then:

```
 @model IEnumerable<Hub.Models.MenuModel>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
           <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.View, item.Controller, item.MenuName)</li>

        }
    </ul>
```

EDIT: Turns out the error thas generates was due to ActionLink() function requiring typed variables. So a simple cast to string fixed it, see below:

```
  @model IEnumerable<Hub.Models.MenuModel>
        <ul>
            @foreach (var item in Model) {
               <li>@Html.ActionLink((string)item.View, (string)item.Controller, (string)item.MenuName)</li>

            }
        </ul>
```

Comment: That markup is in a partial view. So I don't have a controller associated with it. Yet, the first example you give still doesn't work. I'm still lost.

Comment: have you added breakpoints? So you can see what you are passing to the partial view? Is the value set?

Comment: Because VS doesn't like it, I get an error on the page where I've added the partial view. Here is the error : System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Hub.Models.MenuModel>>' has no applicable method named 'ActionLink' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: ahh ok, so what happens is that the items you are passing into the ActionLink() function don't have a type. You can cast them using (string)item.Controller etc. Try if that works.

Comment: No Problem, I'll update my answer to reflect this issue.